# How to Create User with REST Post Request in KeyCloak?

Tags: api, keycloak

Hi I try to create or get users from KeyCloak with an API Request.

My Keycloak Client Configuration is as follows:

```
Client Protocol: openid-connect
Access Type: confidential
Direct Access Grants Enabled: ON
Service Accounts Enabled: ON
```

In `"MyRealm" -> "Cients" -> "Service Account Roles"` in `"Client Roles"` I added `"view-users"` and `"manage-users"`
[image]

After retrieving an Access Token with `"client-id"`, `"client-secret"`, `"username"`, `"password"` and `"grant-type" : "password"` which works fine, I try the following REST API Call:

```
GET http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/MyRealm/users
-Header "Authorization" "Bearer " + {accesstoken}"
```

but I only get {"error":"unknown_error"} back

Same while trying to create a user with

```
POST http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/MyRealm/users
-Header "Authorization" "Bearer " + {accesstoken}"
        "Content-Type"  "application/json"

-Body {"username":"mid",
       "email":"bla@gtestmail.com", 
       "firstName":"mi",
       "lastName":"di",
       "enabled":"true"
       }
```

Do I need to change any specific configurations in Keycloak to get or create Users?

Comment: Do you see any errors (possibly stack traces) in keycloak server logs?

Comment: unfortunately lo log I only get {"error": "unknown_error"} in the json response. Can I extend the logging status somehow?

Comment: Is auth header in the correct format `Authorization: Bearer <accesstoken>`?

Comment: Yes the Auth Header is -Header "Authorization" "Bearer " + {accesstoken}"

Comment: @midi, yes you can increase verbosity in logging subsystem section in KEYCLOAK_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml. Also you can try to search for "unknown_error" occurences in Keycloak sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting above error because your user does not have proper role to query or manage users. You have only added roles to your client using `Service Account Roles`. [image]

Please check if you have roles mentioned in above screenshot added to your users. If you have above roles correctly configured,then your out look something like this

```
[
    {
        "id": "2d274b22-4cd7-4711-ae0d-529615309b57",
        "createdTimestamp": 1632647518630,
        "username": "user1",
        "enabled": true,
        "totp": false,
        "emailVerified": false,
        "firstName": "fname1",
        "lastName": "lname1",
        "email": "user1@localhost",
        "attributes": {
            "picture": [
                "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/90400807?s=96&v=4"
            ],
            "myattribute": [
                "myvalue"
            ]
        },
        "disableableCredentialTypes": [],
        "requiredActions": [],
        "notBefore": 0,
        "access": {
            "manageGroupMembership": true,
            "view": true,
            "mapRoles": true,
            "impersonate": false,
            "manage": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "9d1ed9d9-73e3-4315-bea3-7132d7557c40",
        "createdTimestamp": 1632977937850,
        "username": "user2",
        "enabled": true,
        "totp": false,
        "emailVerified": false,
        "firstName": "firstName2",
        "lastName": "lastName",
        "email": "user2@localhost",
        "disableableCredentialTypes": [],
        "requiredActions": [
            "UPDATE_PROFILE"
        ],
        "notBefore": 0,
        "access": {
            "manageGroupMembership": true,
            "view": true,
            "mapRoles": true,
            "impersonate": false,
            "manage": true
        }
    }
]
```